# Zeros of Eisenstein series for full modular group $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

I am reading the paper "On the zeros of Eisenstein series" [link](http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/2/2/169.full.pdf). In the third paragraph of which it says that, "picking out the four terms with $c^{2}+d^{2}= 1$, we obtain $ F_{k}(\theta)=2 \cos(k \theta/2)+R$".
I am not able to conclude the above observation. $$ $$ Here is my effort: $ $  Since $E_{k}(\theta)$ is uniformly and absolutely convergent ( hence $F_{k}(\theta)$ ). So we can rearrange the double sum by dividing the sum into two parts, first part $c^{2}+d^{2}=1$ and second part $c^{2}+d^{2}>1$. Then,
$$  F_{k}(\theta)= \frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{1}{(e^{i \theta/2}+e^{-i \theta/2})^{k}}+\frac{1}{(e^{i \theta/2}-e^{-i \theta/2})^{k}}+\frac{1}{(-e^{i \theta/2 }+e^{-i \theta/2})^{k}}+\frac{1}{(-e^{i \theta/2}-e^{-i \theta/2})^{k}} \right]+R$$
Since $k$ is even we have that 
$$  F_{k}(\theta)=\frac{1}{(e^{i \theta/2}+e^{-i \theta/2})^{k}}+\frac{1}{(e^{i \theta/2}-e^{-i \theta/2})^{k}}+R$$
Now using $ \cos(a)=(e^{ia}+e^{-ia})/2 $ and $ \sin(a)=(e^{ia}-e^{-ia})/2i $, we get
$$  F_{k}(\theta)=\frac{1}{(2\cos(\theta/2))^{k}}+\frac{1}{(2i \sin(\theta/2))^{k}}+R$$
After this point I got stuck. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: We don't have access to the article (except [1st page](http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/2/2/169.extract)) so make a copy and make your question self-contained

Comment: It's one page paper only.

Comment: Wait his argument seems to be that $F_k(\theta) = e^{i k \theta / 2}E_k(e^{i\theta})$  is real on $\theta \in (\pi/2,2\pi/3)$, not clear why. He finds that $F_k(\theta) =2 \cos( k \theta /2) + R(\theta)$  where $|R(\theta)| < 2$. This bound could be used in [Rouche's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem), but if we know $F_k$ is real it is better. Do you confirm that ?

Comment: $F_{k}(\theta)$ is real for $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ : Observe that the complex conjugate of $ \frac{1}{(c e^{i\theta/2} + d e^{-i \theta })^{k}}$ is $ \frac{1}{(d e^{i\theta/2} + c e^{-i \theta })^{k}}$. then their sum will be a real number and then taking the series of these terms will be real.

Comment: Ok so you are able to write his whole proof in simple words

Comment: In particular, call me when you will be able to explain how we go from "$F_k = \cos + R, |R| < 2$ is real on $(a,b)$" to "$f_k$ has $n$ zeros on $(a,b)$"

Comment: Another proof for $F_{k}(\theta)$ is real for $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$: It is sufficient to show that $\overline{F_{k}}(\theta)=F_{k}(\theta)$.  So, consider  $ \overline{F_{k}(\theta)}$ $= \frac{1}{2} \overline{\sum_{c,d \in \mathbb{Z}\\ (c,d)=1} \frac{1}{(c e^{i \theta/2} +d e^{-i \theta/2})^{k}} } $ $= \sum_{c,d \in \mathbb{Z}\\ (c,d)=1} \frac{1}{(c e^{-i \theta/2} +d e^{i \theta/2})^{k}}.$  Now, if we replace the role of $c,d$ then we get the above expression equals to $F_{k}(\theta)$. Which completes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c^2+d^2=1$ then either $c=\pm 1$ and $d=0$ or $c=0$ and $d=\pm 1$. Moreover, since $k$ is even the term with $c=1,d=0$ is equal to the term with $c=-1,d=0$, and similarly for $c=0,d=\pm 1$.

From the terms $c=\pm 1$, $d=0$ we get $e^{-\frac{ik\theta}{2}}$, and from the terms $c=0,d=\pm 1$ we get $e^{\frac{ik\theta}{2}}$, hence the total is
$$ e^{-\frac{ik\theta}{2}}+e^{\frac{ik\theta}{2}}=2\cos\frac{k\theta}{2}$$

Comment: Thank for pointing out my mistake! :)

Comment: No problem, it's a very nice little paper.